# Not able to find ./bin/spark-class for launching spark cluster on standalone mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While launching standalone cluster on spark streaming, I am not able to find ./bin/spark-class command.

Please let me know, if I need to do any additional configurations for getting "spark-class".

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Spark are you using?  [Starting with Spark 0.9.0](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/releases/spark-release-0-9-0.html#packaging), `spark-class` is located in the [`bin`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/tree/v0.9.0-incubating/bin) folder, but in earlier versions it was at the root of `SPARK_HOME`.

Perhaps you're following instructions for Spark 0.9.0+ even though you've installed an earlier version of Spark?  You can find documentation for older releases of Spark on the Spark [documentation overview page](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/documentation.html).